# one database from two different projects django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-settings

I am having two separate projects which I intent to share a database between them.
The first project called first_project and second called second_project

in the first project I have mysite.db. And I want to use mysite.db in my second project.
I have tried to specify path in settings.py in second_project bet it did not work.

Please suggest me a solution if you know one

Comment: Can you paste the DB settings for both the projects.

Comment: Thank you. Just just use 'connect' to do the trick.
connect = sqlite3.connect("path/to/db")